# how to make sure the mapping of a key doesn't change?

Tags: vim, supertab

I'm on this computer (ubuntu) where <kbd>TAB</kbd> is mapped (I can't find where) to autocomplete. I searched and seems like this is done by supertab, although I couldn't find how to disable it, neither did I find its files.

In my `~/.vimrc` and `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` files, there is no mapping of the tab key. The later file includes `debian.vim` (and tries with `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`, but that doesn't exist) but that also doesn't have any mappings of tab, or any reference to supertab.

The output of `:map!` is this:

```
i  <S-Tab>     * <C-R>=BackwardsSnippet()<CR>
i  <Plug>SuperTabBackward & <C-R>=<SNR>13_SuperTab('p')<CR>
i  <Plug>SuperTabForward & <C-R>=<SNR>13_SuperTab('n')<CR>
i  <C-Tab>     * <Tab>
i  <Tab>       * <C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
i  <CR>        * <C-R>=<SNR>13_SelectCompletion(1)<CR>
i  <C-N>         <Plug>SuperTabForward
i  <C-P>         <Plug>SuperTabBackward
i  <C-R><Tab>  * <C-R>=ShowAvailableSnips()<CR>
i  <C-X>         <C-R>=<SNR>13_ManualCompletionEnter()<CR>
```

Which indicates that supertab is indeed mapping these keys.

I tried putting `nomap! <TAB>` in my `~/.vimrc`, but it doesn't work as it seems like supertab is being loaded *after* `~/.vimrc` is read.

My question is, how can I disable supertab, or alternatively make sure ViM doesn't let anyone map <kbd>TAB</kbd> to anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supertab is a plugin. As such it should be installed somewhere in `~/.vim/`. There are many ways to install plugins (default, pathogen, vundle, etc.). Look into `~/.vim/bundle` (if you use Pathogen) or in `~/.vim/plugin`.

If it's not there it may have been installed in `/usr/share/vim/vim7x/` which is very crowded and should not be touched in any way: good luck.

Anyway, you can do `:verbose map!` to see where the mappings are set (and thus, where the plugin is installed if you want to remove it) or you could simply configure Supertab to not use `<tab>`. See `:help supertab`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to completely get rid of `supertab` you can remap the default keybindings using something like (in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<c-space>'
let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<s-c-space>'
```

If you only want to insert literal <kbd>tab</kbd> characters, supertab makes it easy by mapping literal tabs to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> by default (which unfortunately doesn't work in terminal). It can be customized by using something like:

```
g:SuperTabMappingTabLiteral='<C-`>'
```

Lastly, you can always escape a mapping by prepending it with <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> in insert mode.

see `:h supertab-forwardbackward` for more information. (might not work if you haven't built `supertab` docs)